# Collecting to HashMap to a LinkedHashMap in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am converting HashMap to LinkedHashMap by using java 8 streams. I have the following code:

```
    final LinkedHashMap<String, Employee> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getValue().getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), v -> v.getValue(), (o, o2) -> o, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Everything is clear but the last parameter of the toMap method confuses me a lot.

```
(o, o2) -> o, LinkedHashMap::new)
```

As I understand that is a binaryOperator but I cannot understand how this works exactly and what 'o' means for `o, LinkedHashMap::new`

Can anyone help me to understand it or any better way to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you necessarily want to create a `LinkedHashMap` like this? why not do like `new LinkedHashMap<>(map))`?

Comment: It's a [method reference lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) - which is a `Supplier<LinkedHashMap>`.

Comment: I just want to keep sorted by value.

Comment: These are actually two parameters: 1) `(o, o2) -> o` is a merge function - which is redundant in this case, but needs to be provided because of [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) signature; 2) `LinkedHashMap::new` - supplier of LinkedHashMap

Comment: using only o makes me confused, I was thinking that it is used somehow.

Comment: merge function is used to resolve conflicts to select a value when duplicate keys occur, `(o, o2) -> o`means that the first value remains.  But as long as you are transforming an existing map, all keys are unique and there won't be any collision and therefore this function should not ever be invoked.  This parameter is needed just as a placeholder because `toMap` is not overloaded to provide only `Supplier<Map>` as `groupingBy` collector has.

Comment: Since it is redundant you could probably use `null` instead of `(o, o2) -> o`, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @K.Nicholas no, it does not allow `null`. But you could use `(o1,o2) -> { throw new AssertionError(); }` to clarify that this function should never get evaluated. The advantage is, if this assumption turns out to be wrong, you'll notice instead of silently dropping entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(o, o2) -> o` is the 3rd parameter

As the documentation says

> @param mergeFunction a merge function, used to resolve collisions
> between
> *                      values associated with the same key, as supplied
> *                      to {@link Map#merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)}

This means that if you have a conflict you keep only `o`. You don't care about the other conflicting object `o2`. So `o` and `o2` are 2 conflicting values that exist for the same key.